# How to apply a specific syntax to a range within a file?

Tags: syntax-highlighting

My cypher files are properly highlighted, however I have python files that include large texts of cypher like so

[image]

I would like the cypher part to be have the same cypher syntax highlighting like so
[image]

I asked chat gpt, and it recommended this solution

```
syntax include @Cypher syntax/cypher.vim
syntax region cypherCode start=+f"""+ end=+"""+ contains=@Cypher
```

I tried that, didn't work.

For reference here is my current setup for cypher highlighting

```
" for some reason Plugin 'memgraph/cypher.vim' fails to autodetect
" the cypher file type, so we do it manually here
" https://stackoverflow.com/a/28117335/766570
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cypher setfiletype cypher
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cql setfiletype cypher
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.cyp setfiletype cypher
```

Comment: that is in the general case not easily possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unlet `b:current_syntax` before including another one.
Additionally in `syntax region` you need to `matchgroup` for start/end

Following works for me:

```
unlet! b:current_syntax
syntax include @Cypher syntax/cypher.vim
syntax region cypherCode matchgroup=String start=+f"""+ end=+"""+ contains=@Cypher keepend
```

[image]

PS:

[image: asciicast]

PPS: if you want this syntax addition to be applied for all python files, add those lines to `~/.vim/after/syntax/python.vim`.

Comment: Nice it worked! however I could only make it work by making your code a vim function and applying it after the buffer loads.

Isn't there a way to make it load automatically?

Comment: @abbood well, you didn't ask about it, I assumed you know how to do it :)

Comment: Wow very interesting

Comment: one last thing, how can this thing be undone? I want to create a keybinding where i can toggle it on/off

Comment: try `:syntax clear cypherCode`